# JAXB Naming Collision Salesforce Integration

Tags: salesforce, myeclipse, jaxb2

I'm attempting to integrate with Salesforce using MyEclipse. The wizard fails because of a naming collision on a complex type "DescribeLayout". I need to write a JAXB binding file to ensure that the two interfaces that are created by the xjc compiler are in different packages, but I have absolutely no idea how to do this.

I do not have the URI's to the schemas that make up the WSDL, only the URN's.

Comment: Please describe the cause - is it an element and a type with the same name in the same namespace? If so, there's plenty of help in the JAXB projects' documentation, such as http://jaxb.java.net/guide/Dealing_with_errors.html

Answer (score 1):

This blog post shows how to append a suffix to type names to avoid this. I'm not a JAXB expert, but presumably there is a way to configure it to use a different package instead of a suffix.

http://blog.teamlazerbeez.com/2009/05/23/salesforcecom-partner-soap-api-jax-ws-tutorial-part-1/